# Disable mouse move event over menu separator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Is it possible to disable the mouse move over menu separator?

while scrolling over menu using keyboard keys, it's skipping the menu separator. is the same thing possible for mouse?

Comment: If you do that you will confuse people. You should go with what people are used to, and what is the usual thing on their operating system.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to identify the separator position during mouse move?

Comment: What are you going to do with the information?

Comment: I have a banner(bitmap image) on the left side of the menu. It gets erased while moving mouse over menu,only in the place where the menu separator is placed. This is what i am going to do? can u help me?

Comment: So are you drawing it as an owner-draw menu?

Answer (score 0):

To do an owner draw menu, see this tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756947.aspx